# Why is the caption without caption package within the box and with caption outside?

Tags: captions

I have the following code, which works fine when package caption is
inactive. However with caption the title of the "steckbrief" moves out
of the box. What is it that caption changes that the title moves to the
outside?

I had previously the boxedminipae environment gone into the \fs@my block
but that produced overfull boxes. Removing the \fs@my block puts the
caption below the factsheet.

Any help appreciated.

Kind regards

Bernhard

(this has been asked on comp.text.tex without any answer.)

```
    \documentclass[fontsize=10pt,twoside,draft]{scrbook}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=13.5cm,textheight=22cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{calc,boxedminipage2e,float, capt-of}
%\usepackage{caption}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\fs@my{%Caption im Rahmen
\let\@fs@capt\floatc@plain
\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue%
\def\@fs@mid{}%
\def\@fs@pre{}%
\def\@fs@post{}%
}
\floatstyle{my}
\newfloat{factsheet}{hbtp}{los} % Steckbrief, Factsheet
\floatname{factsheet}{Factsheet}
\newlength{\figurewidth}\setlength{\figurewidth}{11.5cm}
\newcounter{stbr}
\newenvironment{FS}[3]%factsheet
{\begin{boxedminipage}{1\figurewidth}\centering%begindef
\captionof{figure}{\textbf{#2}}\label{fs:#3}%
\refstepcounter{stbr}
\begin{list}{}%
{\renewcommand\makelabel[1]{\bfseries\footnotesize{##1}\hfil}%
\settowidth\labelwidth{\makelabel{#1}}%
\setlength\leftmargin{\labelwidth+\labelsep}\footnotesize}% 
}
{  \end{list}%enddefinition
 \end{boxedminipage}%
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{factsheet*}[b!]
\centering
\begin{FS}{Bildung und Ziel}%
 {Thyrotropin"=Releasing Hormon}{trh}
\item [Gen]Chromosom: 3; Genort: 3q13.3-q21
\item [Sequenz]\textbf{p{EHP}-NH$_2$}
\item [Bildung und Ziel] TRH wird vor allem im{PVN} gebildet...
\end{FS}
\end{factsheet*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Your example does not compile

Comment: it does now, sorry

Comment: Related: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/de.comp.text.tex/ow-XIRlbgmU

Comment: it looks the same but is not, in that topic it was the overfull boxes, which here are avoided. Here it is a strange behaviour of caption that I donot understand and which has not been answered in the  comp.text.tex newsgroup.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? If you want this to be a new type of float, then why would you want the caption to be as if it was a `figure`? **caption** is sensitive to this kind of new float, and therefore tries to do the right thing. But that assumes that what you are asking it to do makes sense. Here, it really doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without `caption` package, `\captionof{figure}` simply expands to `\def\@captype{figure}\caption`. `\caption` has been redefined by the `float` package. The `float` package author has decided to make this redefinition globally. (A different approach would be redefining `\caption` only inside own environments.) Since the redefinition is globally, the new code of `\caption` needs something to detect if it was called within a float controlled by the `float` package or not. It uses the following code:

```
\ifx \csname @float@c@\@captype \endcsname \relax
% no environment of the float package
\else
% environment controlled by the float package
\fi
```

So what happens when compiling your code? The environment `factsheet` starts. `\captionof` is used which changes `\@captype` from `factsheet` to `figure` and uses `\caption` afterwards. `\caption` checks for `\ifx \csname @float@c@\@captype \endcsname \relax` which is true since `\@captype` was redefined from `factsheet` to `figure` and `figure` is not controlled by the `float` package. So the `float` package thinks it's not responsible for this caption and therefore the ordinary caption code will be used. As result the caption will be typeset inside the box and there is no caption outside the box since the `float` package behaves as there was no `\caption` inside `factsheet` at all.

In total your code uses the following undocumented(!) facts:

1. `\caption` is redefined by the `float` package globally
2. `\caption` uses `\@captype` to distinguish between ordinary floating environments and ones controlled by the `float` package

If the implementation of the `float` package would differ in only one of these two points your caption would be typeset outside the box, since this is the documented(!) way the `float` package operates. The only reason why it's typeset inside the box (which is the unexpected behaviour!) is that using `\captionof` makes the check of the `float` package doomed to fail. (Try using `\caption` instead of `\captionof` and you'll see that the caption won't be inside the box either.)

Remember: You have even told the `float` package where to put captions of `factsheet`: `\let\@fs@iftopcapt\iftrue` which means "Typeset the caption on top of the float body".

If you don't want the caption to be typeset outside the float body, one could use the documented(!) way to tell this to the `float` package:

> There is a \restylefloat* command which will restyle an existing float type but will keep the new float style from taking over the \caption command. In this case the user is responsible for handling their own captions.

So adding `\restylefloat*{factsheet}` right after `\newfloat{factsheet}...` is the documented way to tell the `float` package that you would like to typeset the caption inside the float body and not outside.

So far I have answered the question "Why is the caption typeset inside the box which is opposite to the documented and therefore expected behavior of the `float` package?". Now I would like to answer "Why is the caption without caption package within the box and with caption outside?". Well that's an easy one. Since the `caption` package redefines `\caption` as well it cannot emulate every internal implementation detail of the `float` package (and all the other packages the new `\caption` code has to work with). Instead it tries to emulate the documented behavior of the packages (or as cfr has expressed it in the comments above: "tries to do the right thing"), which means in your case: "Typeset the caption outside the float body, on top of it."

So when adding `\restylefloat*{factsheet}` you should see the same behavior with and without `caption` package.

BTW: Why are you defining `factsheet` anyway, why don't you simply use `figure` and `\caption` instead of `factsheet` and `\captionof{figure}`?

Comment: Thank you! factsheets are supposed to contain condensed information in my book about a hormone and a hormone building enzyme, figures are for illustrations

Comment: When you change
`\def\@fs@pre{}%

\def\@fs@post{}%`
to 
`\def\@fs@pre{\setlength{\fboxsep}{2pt}\begin{boxedminipage}[t][\relax][c]{0.96\linewidth}}%

\def\@fs@post{\end{boxedminipage}}`
than you see that the outer box is to large by some pt. I have difficulties to understand this. I have already asked Scott Pakin and I also has no idea. I would appreciate if you have a solution for this problem.

Bernhard

Comment: @BernhardKleine I will take a look at it at Saturday, and report.

Comment: @BernhardKleine When I add `\restylefloat*{factsheet}` and make your code changes, I get no difference between "without caption package" and "with caption package". What difference do you get?

Comment: sorry I dit not see your comment. I will check and come back